# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive in web config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

When i host my project in godaddy i got a error Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
My Web.config.Please help me.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>

      </connectionStrings>
      <!--
        For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

        The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
          <system.Web>
            <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
          </system.Web>
      -->
      <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <authentication mode="None"/>
        <sessionState timeout="50000"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
        <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
        <trust level="Full"/>
      </system.web>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
          <files>
            <clear/>
            <add value="Default.aspx"/>
          </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Several answers for this issue already on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890565/unrecognized-attribute-targetframework-note-that-attribute-names-are-case-sen)

Comment: i try it bt got same error

Comment: Please update your question, describing what you have tried in detail.